# Replace consecutive characters in a string

Tags: java, regex

I need to replace all consecutive single quotes with a single double quote:

```
// ''Hello World''     -> "Hello World"
// '''It's me.''''     -> "It's me."
// ''''Oh'' ''No'''    -> "Oh" "No"
// ''This'''Is''Fine'' -> "This"Is"Fine"
```

I feel like this can be solved with a regex, but I don't know where to start.

Here is my current solution:

```
private fix(String line) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) {
        builder.append("'");
    }
    while (builder.length() > 1) {
        line = line.replace(builder.toString(), "\"");
        builder.deleteCharAt(0);
    }
    return line;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different so-called quantifiers to define that a character can/must be repeated a given number of time.

Probably the most known are * (zero or more occurences) and + (one or more occurences). The quantifier that is of help for you in your case is {2,} which means "two or more occurences". This is a specialization of the more general {*min occurences*,*max occurences*} quantifier.

So you can do it like that:

```
line.replaceAll("'{2,}", "\"");
```

In the JavaDocs its defined at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy